# nexus 7 set to stand by all the time

Tags: android

We are using a nexus 7 to run only one app as an interface.

What we woudl like is that when the screen goes blank to save power it will cone back on when touched without having to press the button on the top of the device.

Is there a way to do this in the settings ? can i be done by adding code in out app or is there a third party app I could run in the backgroung.

The device will be glued into a docking station so power is not an issue but in needs to go blank so it is not a source on light at night but be able to wake up and function with a touch of the screen.

Comment: AFAIK the only way would be to make your own idle listener and when the device has been idle long enough put a full screen black view on the screen so it will appear to be off. Your app will have to keep a wakelock so that the device never actually "goes to sleep" if it gets into the sleep state the only way to wake it up is with the power button, it cannot react to any screen touch events.

Answer (score 0):

> What we woudl like is that when the screen goes blank to save power it will cone back on when touched without having to press the button on the top of the device.

You will need to build your own hardware for that. While you can turn the screen brightness as far down as you want, the screen has to stay powered on in order to receive touch events, in conventional Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this a custom application but you probably aren't going to like the answer.

We modified the kernel screen brightness control so that when the brightness was set to a minumum .01 it would deactivate the backlight and make it appear to be off.

If you actually turn the brightness off as CommonsWare says the touch sensor will be deactivated.

The other solution that might work for is listen for screen off intent, once that fires start a service that monitor the g-sensor and once reaches a threshold value you determined is enough you can acquire a wakelock that will brighten the screen. This is the only way I know how to accomplish close to what you are asking with out hardware or kernel changes.